# How cakephp associations work?

Tags: cakephp

I'm new to cakephp, looking for more practical examples on cakephp associations, after searching hours in google, but not found exact explanation. Can anybody explain how associations work in cakephp, and how can these be useful for fast website development?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean model associations ?

Comment: First sorry for not specifying complete name, Yes I want to know more about model associations.

Comment: please add your table relationship

Comment: `class User extends AppModel{public $name='User';}` `class Profile extends AppModel{}` We have user_id field in Profile table, So how can I use model associations to relate these two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Profile Model add following relation

```
var $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
         'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        ),
    );
```

In User Model add this

```
var $hasMany = array(
            'Profile' => array(
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            ));
```

In Controller you can use these associations like this

```
class MyController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $data = $this->User->findAll();
        Debug($data);

        $data1 = $this->Profile->findAll();
        Debug($data1);

    }
```

For more detail regarding model association read [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html).